# ATXMEGA128A4 and bluetooth BTM-331

Tags: c, bluetooth, avr, atmega

I have some questions regarding atxmega128a4. I want to use all of its 5 uart modules but my very basic problem is that I do not know what are the pins for RX/TX. I have read in manual but I cannot find this. Can anyone help me? Can you configure from software what of the pins are tx/rx?(the ports are mentioned in datasheet but not the particular pins,because of this I cannot do my PCB:()

http://www.atmel.com/devices/atxmega128a4u.aspx

The second part of this post is about bluetooth BTM-331. I want to use one of atxmega uart to communicate with this module. 
First of all, if I power up the bluetooth should I be able to discover it from my laptop? 
Secondly,must the reset be put at ground?(in the datasheet says the reset pin is high for > 5ms will cause a reset) If I let the reset unconected will I have always "1" and the module is in permanent reset? 
The last very stupid question about this module. Is the 1 pin on bottom left(regarding FIRST PHOTO)? The datasheet is also confusing.

http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/655d5da34b456d9bc96554c46e9251dd/btm-331.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: ok , thanks. first part of my question was solved, the part with the bluetooth still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fig 1 on page 5 of BTM-Datasheet contains numbering of Pins

Are you sure you read '1' on reset input? Since it is stated that the input is debounced it seems to be inteded that it may be connected to some reset button that should be switch to high then pressed to trigger high active reset input. 
Also if its pulled up and you need to keep it pulled to ground to not reset that would constantly draw an small amount of current, which you normally want to reduce as much as possible since bluetooth devices mostly are battery powered.

The datasheet itself is not very comprehensive. it does not even contain information about energy consumption or how to access the eeprom